# Sharepoint app put file in stream

Tags: 2013, error, sharepoint-addin

I have a Sharepoint app with a button in the app web that sends information about the selected item to the host web. Here I want to put the selected document in a stream. I have tried several methods but I either get an error 401: unauthorized or error 403 forbidden.

The information I send when clicking the button:

```
<UrlAction Url="~remoteAppUrl/Pages/Default.aspx?HostUrl={HostUrl}&amp;Source={Source}&amp;ListUrlDir={ListUrlDir}&amp;SPListItemId={ItemId}&amp;SPListId={ListId}" />
```

On Default.aspx I get the selected item with the following code:

```
using (var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(hostWeb, accessToken))
{
List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetById(listId);
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item = list.GetItemById(listItemId);

clientContext.Load(item);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

var fileRef = (string)item["FileRef"];
}
```

Now i want to put fileref in a stream but no matter what I try I always get an error.
One of the things I tried:

```
//get the file contents:
    FileInformation fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileRef.ToString());

using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
{
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 64];
int nread = 0;
while ((nread = fileInfo.Stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
memory.Write(buffer, 0, nread);
}
memory.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
// ... here you have the contents of your file in memory, 
// do whatever you want
}
```

For this I get the error 403: forbidden on the line:

```
FileInformation fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileRef.ToString());
```

How can I get the item into a stream?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer on this blog: http://tech-karma.blogspot.be/2013/05/sharepoint-2013-online-app-403-response.html

I changed the code so it doesn't download the file to disk but puts it in a MemoryStream

```
public void PutInStream(ClientContext context, string fileNameInDocumentLib, Guid listID)
        {
            //Find the file by name
            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View>
                            <Query>
                                <Where>
                                <Eq>
                                    <FieldRef Name=""FileLeafRef"" />
                                    <Value Type=""Text"">" + fileNameInDocumentLib + @"</Value>
                                </Eq>
                                </Where>
                                </Query>
                            </View>";

            //Get list item
            List list = context.Web.Lists.GetById(listID);
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
            context.Load(listItems);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            if (listItems.Count > 0)
            {
                var item = listItems.First();
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file = item.File;
                ClientResult<Stream> data = file.OpenBinaryStream();

                //Load the Stream data for the file
                context.Load(file);
                context.ExecuteQuery();

                //If data received, upload to Azure blob storage
                if (data != null)
                {
                    using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 64];
                        int nread = 0;

                        while ((nread = data.Value.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            memory.Write(buffer, 0, nread);
                        }
                        memory.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                        //Here you have the file in MemoryStream (memory) and you can use it
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Very interesting, do you know how instead of first downloading the whole source stream first one could hook up the source and the target directly?